# how to solve RTCIceServer.url is deprecated! Use urls instead ?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, webrtc

i installed nodejs with soket.io. 
 want to test this code to the server node server.js

```html
var static = require('node-static');
var http = require('http');
// Create a node-static server instance listening on port 8181
var file = new(static.Server)();
// We use the http module’s createServer function and
// use our instance of node-static to serve the files
var app = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
file.serve(req, res);
}).listen(8181);
// Use socket.io JavaScript library for real-time web applications
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
// Let's start managing connections...
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket){
// Handle 'message' messages
socket.on('message', function (message) {
log('S --> Got message: ', message);
socket.broadcast.to(message.channel).emit('message', \
message.message);
});
// Handle 'create or join' messages
socket.on('create or join', function (channel) {
var numClients = io.sockets.clients(channel).length;
console.log('numclients = ' + numClients);
// First client joining...
if (numClients == 0){
socket.join(channel);
socket.emit('created', channel);
// Second client joining...
} else if (numClients == 1) {
// Inform initiator...
io.sockets.in(channel).emit('remotePeerJoining', channel);
// Let the new peer join channel
socket.join(channel);
socket.broadcast.to(channel).emit('broadcast: joined', 'S --> \
broadcast(): client ' + socket.id + ' joined channel ' \
+ channel);
} else { // max two clients
console.log("Channel full!");
socket.emit('full', channel);
}
});
// Handle 'response' messages
socket.on('response', function (response) {
log('S --> Got response: ', response);
// Just forward message to the other peer
socket.broadcast.to(response.channel).emit('response',
response.message);
});
// Handle 'Bye' messages
socket.on('Bye', function(channel){
// Notify other peer
socket.broadcast.to(channel).emit('Bye');
// Close socket from server's side
socket.disconnect();
});
// Handle 'Ack' messages
socket.on('Ack', function () {
console.log('Got an Ack!');
// Close socket from server's side
socket.disconnect();
});
// Utility function used for remote logging
function log(){
var array = [">>> "];
for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
array.push(arguments[i]);
}
socket.emit('log', array);
}
});
```

and client.js

```js
<script>
// Get <div> placeholder element from DOM
div = document.getElementById('scratchPad');
// Connect to server
var socket = io.connect();
// Ask channel name from user
channel = prompt("Enter signaling channel name:");
if (channel !== "") {
console.log('Trying to create or join channel: ', channel);
// Send 'create or join' to the server
socket.emit('create or join', channel);
}
// Handle 'created' message
socket.on('created', function (channel){
console.log('channel ' + channel + ' has been created!');
console.log('This peer is the initiator...');
// Dynamically modify the HTML5 page
div.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeEnd', '<p>Time: ' +(performance.now() / 1000).toFixed(3) + ' --> Channel '+ channel + ' has been created! </p>');
div.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeEnd', '<p>Time: ' +(performance.now() / 1000).toFixed(3) +' --> This peer is the initiator...</p>');
});
// Handle 'full' message
socket.on('full', function (channel){console.log('channel ' + channel + ' is too crowded! Cannot allow you to enter, sorry :-(');
div.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeEnd', '<p>Time: ' +(performance.now() / 1000).toFixed(3) + ' --> channel ' + channel + ' is too crowded! Cannot allow you to enter sorry :-( </p>');
});
// Handle 'remotePeerJoining' message
socket.on('remotePeerJoining', function (channel){
console.log('Request to join ' + channel);
console.log('You are the initiator!');
div.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeEnd', '<p style="color:red">Time: ' +(performance.now() / 1000).toFixed(3) +' --> Message from server: request to join channel ' +channel + '</p>');
});
// Handle 'joined' message
socket.on('joined', function (msg){
console.log('Message from server: ' + msg);div.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeEnd', '<p>Time: ' +(performance.now() / 1000).toFixed(3) +' --> Message from server: </p>');
div.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeEnd', '<p style="color:blue">' +msg + '</p>');
div.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeEnd', '<p>Time: ' +(performance.now() / 1000).toFixed(3) +' --> Message from server: </p>');
div.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeEnd', '<p style="color:blue">' +msg + '</p>');
});
// Handle 'broadcast: joined' message
socket.on('broadcast: joined', function (msg){
div.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeEnd', '<p style="color:red">Time: ' +(performance.now() / 1000).toFixed(3) +' --> Broadcast message from server: </p>');
div.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeEnd', '<p style="color:red">' +msg + '</p>');
console.log('Broadcast message from server: ' + msg);
// Start chatting with remote peer:
// 1. Get user's message
var myMessage = prompt('Insert message to be sent to your peer:', "");
// 2. Send to remote peer (through server)
socket.emit('message', {
channel: channel,
message: myMessage});
});
// Handle remote logging message from server
socket.on('log', function (array){
console.log.apply(console, array);
});
// Handle 'message' message
socket.on('message', function (message){
console.log('Got message from other peer: ' + message);
div.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeEnd', '<p>Time: ' +(performance.now() / 1000).toFixed(3) +' --> Got message from other peer: </p>');
div.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeEnd', '<p style="color:blue">' +message + '</p>');
// Send back response message:
// 1. Get response from user
var myResponse = prompt('Send response to other peer:', "");
// 2. Send it to remote peer (through server)
socket.emit('response', {
channel: channel,
message: myResponse});
});
// Handle 'response' message
socket.on('response', function (response){
console.log('Got response from other peer: ' + response);
div.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeEnd', '<p>Time: ' +(performance.now() / 1000).toFixed(3) +' --> Got response from other peer: </p>');
div.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeEnd', '<p style="color:blue">' +response + '</p>');
// Keep on chatting
var chatMessage = prompt('Keep on chatting. Write "Bye" to quit conversation', "");
// User wants to quit conversation: send 'Bye' to remote party
if(chatMessage == "Bye"){
div.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeEnd', '<p>Time: ' +(performance.now() / 1000).toFixed(3) +' --> Sending "Bye" to server...</p>');
console.log('Sending "Bye" to server');
socket.emit('Bye', channel);
div.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeEnd', '<p>Time: ' +(performance.now() / 1000).toFixed(3) +' --> Going to disconnect...</p>');
console.log('Going to disconnect...');
// Disconnect from server
socket.disconnect();
}else{
// Keep on going: send response back
// to remote party (through server)
socket.emit('response', {
channel: channel,
message: chatMessage});
}
});
// Handle 'Bye' message
socket.on('Bye', function (){
console.log('Got "Bye" from other peer! Going to disconnect...');
div.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeEnd', '<p>Time: ' +(performance.now() / 1000).toFixed(3) +' --> Got "Bye" from other peer!</p>');
div.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeEnd', '<p>Time: ' +(performance.now() / 1000).toFixed(3) +' --> Sending "Ack" to server</p>');
// Send 'Ack' back to remote party (through server)
console.log('Sending "Ack" to server');
socket.emit('Ack');
// Disconnect from server
div.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeEnd', '<p>Time: ' +(performance.now() / 1000).toFixed(3)+' --> Going to disconnect...</p>');
console.log('Going to disconnect...');
socket.disconnect();
});
```

but when I do node server.js to prompt I have this error

```
 Missing error handler on 'socket'.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined
at Socket.<anonymous> <c:\Users\Desktop\exe\ser.js:15:45>
 `at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
`at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
`at Socket.onevent (C:\Users\Desktop\exe\node_modules\socket.io\lib\so
cket.js:335:8)
at Socket.onpacket (C:\Users\Desktop\exe\node_modules\socket.io\lib\s
ocket.js:295:12)
at Client.ondecoded (C:\Users\Desktop\exe\node_modules\socket.io\lib\
client.js:193:14)
 at Decoder.Emitter.emit (C:\Users\Kiara\Desktop\exe4\node_modules\socket.io\
```

node_modules\socket.io-parser\node_modules\component-emitter\index.js:134:20)
  `at Decoder.add(C:\Users\Kiara\Desktop\exe4\node_modules\socket.io\node_modu`
 les\socket.io-parser\index.js:247:12)
   `at Client.ondata (C:\Users\Kiara\Desktop\exe4\node_modules\socket.io\lib\cli
ent.js:175:18)`
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)

and I get firefox

RTCIceServer.url is deprecated! Use urls instead.

how to solve ?

Comment: The Firefox warning you get is an RTCPeerConnection configuration error, but you're not showing us any WebRTC code!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

(I'm answering you subject, since the rest of your question seemed unrelated).

The Firefox web console warning `"RTCIceServer.url is deprecated! Use urls instead"` refers to your RTCPeerConnection configuration.

Locate code similar to this:

```
var pc = new RTCPeerConnection({ iceServers: [{ url: 'stun:foo.com:1234' }] });
```

and rename it to:

```
var pc = new RTCPeerConnection({ iceServers: [{ urls: 'stun:foo.com:1234' }] });
                                                   ^
```

The name changed, because each ice server may in fact have multiple ways (URLs) in which it can be located, depending on network topology.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCIceServer/url This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it.