# Remote video is black screen or blank in WebRTC

Tags: webrtc

I have signaling server in java  and websocket.
It works well with local video. but Remote video is black screen or blank 
But it is not always a blank. If you turn off the server and turn it on again, the remote video will show up on your remote.
Why does not it always come out sometimes, and sometimes it does not come out?

this is my code...

```
 navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;
window.RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
window.RTCIceCandidate = window.RTCIceCandidate || window.mozRTCIceCandidate || window.webkitRTCIceCandidate;
window.RTCSessionDescription = window.RTCSessionDescription || window.mozRTCSessionDescription || window.webkitRTCSessionDescription;
window.SpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition || window.mozSpeechRecognition
        || window.msSpeechRecognition || window.oSpeechRecognition;

    var localVideoStream = null;
var peerConn = null,
        wsc = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/signaling"),
        peerConnCfg = {
            'iceServers': [{
                'url': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
            }]
        };


var videoCallButton = document.getElementById("caller");
var       endCallButton = document.getElementById("callee");
var     localVideo = document.getElementById('localVideo');
var     remoteVideo = document.getElementById('remoteVideo');
videoCallButton.addEventListener("click", initiateCall);

endCallButton.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
            wsc.send(JSON.stringify({"closeConnection": true }));
        });
var sdpConstraints = {
    'mandatory': {
        'OfferToReceiveAudio': true,
        'OfferToReceiveVideo': true
    }
};
function prepareCall() {
    peerConn = new RTCPeerConnection(peerConnCfg);
    // send any ice candidates to the other peer
    peerConn.onicecandidate = onIceCandidateHandler;
    // once remote stream arrives, show it in the remote video element
    peerConn.onaddstream = onAddStreamHandler;
};

// run start(true) to initiate a call
function initiateCall() {
    prepareCall();
    // get the local stream, show it in the local video element and send it
    navigator.getUserMedia({ "audio": true, "video": true }, function (stream) {
        localVideoStream = stream;
        localVideo.src = URL.createObjectURL(localVideoStream);
        peerConn.addStream(localVideoStream);
        createAndSendOffer();

    }, function(error) { console.log(error);});
};

function answerCall() {
    prepareCall();
    // get the local stream, show it in the local video element and send it
    navigator.getUserMedia({ "audio": true, "video": true }, function (stream) {
        localVideoStream = stream;
        localVideo.src = URL.createObjectURL(localVideoStream);
        peerConn.addStream(localVideoStream);
        createAndSendAnswer();

    }, function(error) { console.log(error);});
};

wsc.onmessage = function (evt) {
    var signal = null;
    if (!peerConn) answerCall();
    signal = JSON.parse(evt.data);

    if (signal.sdp) {
        console.log("Received SDP from remote peer.");
        console.log("signal"+ signal);
        peerConn.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(signal.sdp));
    }
    else if (signal.candidate) {
        console.log("signal"+ signal.candidate);
        console.log("Received ICECandidate from remote peer.");
        peerConn.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(signal.candidate));
    } else if ( signal.closeConnection){
        console.log("Received 'close call' signal from remote peer.");
        endCall();
    }else{
        console.log("signal"+ signal.candidate);
    }
};

function createAndSendOffer() {
    peerConn.createOffer(
            function (offer) {
                var off = new RTCSessionDescription(offer);
                peerConn.setLocalDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(off),
                        function() {
                            wsc.send(JSON.stringify({"sdp": off }));
                        },
                        function(error) { console.log(error);}
                );
            },
            function (error) { console.log(error);}
    );
};

function createAndSendAnswer() {
    peerConn.createAnswer(
            function (answer) {
                var ans = new RTCSessionDescription(answer);
                peerConn.setLocalDescription(ans, function() {
                            wsc.send(JSON.stringify({"sdp": ans }));
                        },
                        function (error) { console.log(error);}
                );
            },
            function (error) {console.log(error);}
    );
};

function onIceCandidateHandler(evt) {
    if (!evt || !evt.candidate) return;
    wsc.send(JSON.stringify({"candidate": evt.candidate }));
};

function onAddStreamHandler(evt) {
    videoCallButton.setAttribute("disabled", true);
    endCallButton.removeAttribute("disabled");
    // set remote video stream as source for remote video HTML5 element

    remoteVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(evt.stream);
    remoteVideo.play();
    console.log("remote src : "+ remoteVideo.src);
};

function endCall() {
    peerConn.close();
    peerConn = null;
    videoCallButton.removeAttribute("disabled");
    endCallButton.setAttribute("disabled", true);
    if (localVideoStream) {
        localVideoStream.getTracks().forEach(function (track) {
            track.stop();
        });
        localVideo.src = "";
    }
    if (remoteVideo){
        remoteVideo.src = "";
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(remoteVideo);
    }
};
```

Comment: Some outdated code here. [Use `urls`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37260021/918910), and [avoid outdated offer options](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28323941/918910).

Comment: You're not checking for errors on `setRemoteDescription`, and you have a typo where you're calling `new RTCSessionDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer))`, but other than that I don't see anything wrong. Fix the `urls` to see if it helps, and check if you're getting ICE candidates.

Comment: I fixed that part as you said. but.. The results were unchanged. There is a time when remote video comes out well and there is a time when it does not come out, and I do not know what the difference is. I'm getting tired ...Obviously the video stream is well received. However, putting it in a video tag does not show the other party.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `oniceconnectionstatechange` to your prepeareCall Function and see if there is any ICE failure because of NAT issues

```
function prepareCall() {
    peerConn = new RTCPeerConnection(peerConnCfg);
    // send any ice candidates to the other peer
    peerConn.onicecandidate = onIceCandidateHandler;
    // once remote stream arrives, show it in the remote video element
    peerConn.onaddstream = onAddStreamHandler;
    peerConn.oniceconnectionstatechange = function(){
       console.log('ICE state: ',peerConn.iceConnectionState);
    }
};
```

Comment: wow... You did as you told me. Then the checking string appeared in the log.I have searched for it. The meaning of checking is  "The ICE agent has been given one or more remote candidates and is checking pairs of local and remote candidates against one another to try to find a compatible match, but has not yet found a pair which will allow the peer connection to be made. It's possible that gathering of candidates is also still underway."
So what should I do?

Answer (score 4):

One of the reasons for WebRTC blank / empty video is having high packet loss. In that scenario, in server and client logs it will show as the connection is successful and video is playing normally, so you won't see any warning or error.

To check if there is a high packet loss, you can go to `about:webrtc` on firefox, or `chrome://webrtc-internals` on chrome. For firefox, you can navigate to "RTP Stats". You'll see it shows `Received: ... packets` and `Lost: ... packets`. You can calculate packet loss ratio using these counts. For chrome, there is a graph for packet loss ratio. You might have a very high packet loss such as 70% for example.

If you have this extreme high packet loss, one reason is having a smaller MTU https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit on the client network interface than the MTU used by the server. For example, your client network interface can have MTU=1500 bytes when not connected to VPN, and MTU=1250 bytes when connected to VPN. If the server is sending RTP packets (over UDP) with MTU=1400, it can be received by the client if the client is not using VPN, but the packets larger than 1250 bytes will get dropped by the client network interface.

If you want to check the client MTU locally, you can run `ifconfig` on mac or linux.

Mac example, without example vpn:

```
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ...
    inet SOME_IP netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
    media: autoselect
    status: active
```

Mac example, with example vpn:

```
utun2: flags=80d1<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST> mtu 1250
    inet SOME_IP --> SOME_IP netmask 0xffffffff
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
```

How to configure MTU for server:

If you are using GStreamer for WebRTC server, the payload generator element, for example `rtpvp8pay` has a property to set desired MTU value.
By using `gst-inspect-1.0 rtpvp8pay` you can see that it uses 1400 as MTU by default which can be larger than your client network interface can handle (e.g. 1250 on above example).
You can make it work by setting lower MTU on your GStreamer pipeline so that your client network interface won't drop majority of the packages anymore (package loss ratio can reduce to 0.01% just by changing MTU on GStreamer pipeline on the server).

When this is the case, the incoming video can work for ~10 seconds when VPN is freshly reconnected, then the incoming video can freeze and subsequent page refreshes can lead to just blank video with 70%+ packet loss.

This is a very specific scenario but when it happens it is a complete silent/hidden error so hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

in func did recieve remote video track perform a timer then in timer selector add track to view